# Why does nextjs 13 load .env.local during build process?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

[The docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) state, that

> .env.local is where secrets can be stored.

But then, why does `next build` even load the `.env.local` file during the build process?

Isn't it supposed to work like this: Build once, run everywhere?

Comment: The `.env.local` file contains credentials in key-value format for services used by the program. It's meant to be stored locally and not be uploaded to code repositories online for everyone to read.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question..

Comment: What exactly should "Isn't it supposed to work like this: Build once, run everywhere?" mean, especially in the context of environment variables. Please edit your question and make it more concise.